# Discord.js V12 How can I lock all channels for a certain role?

Tags: javascript, locking, discord.js, channel

I want to lock all channels in the server to a certain role (Send messages: false)
This is my current code, the error I get is `TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied overwrites is not an Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites.`
Code:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "modrek")) {
        let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Mute")
        const channels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type !== "category")
        
        message.guild.channels.forEach(ch => 
            {
            if(ch.type == "text")
              ch.overwritePermissions([
              {
                 id: muteRole.id,
                 deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
              },
            ], 'Needed to change permissions');
            }) 
    
    }

})
```

Let me know if someone can help me out :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[overwritePermissions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) will replace the permission overwrites in the channel that means if the channel had previous permission overwrites it will replace them all.

In that case ->

```js
message.channel.overwritePermissions([
  {
     id: muteRole.id,
     deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
  },
], 'Needed to change permissions');
```

[createOverwrite](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=createOverwrite) will Overwrite the permissions for a user or role in this channel. (replaces if existent)

In that ->

```js
message.channel.createOverwrite(muteRole, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false
    })
    }
```

Modify permissions for all channels ->

```
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(ch => 
{
if(ch.type == "text")
  ch.overwritePermissions([
  {
     id: muteRole.id,
     deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
  },
], 'Needed to change permissions');
})
```

Comment: I've used the first one, thanks. That only locks the channel where the command is executed, how could I lock ALL channels for that role?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function
I'll update the original one with my current code

Comment: I forgot to add `.cache` just change it