# How to make my discord bot update channel permissions as an action?

Tags: javascript, permissions, discord, discord.js, bots

So I do have this simple function here, where my bot sends a message to a specific channel after 10 secs. I want to somehow make my bot not only send the message, but also automatically edit the (SEND_MESSAGES) channel permissions to @everyone

```
setTimeout(function() {
      client.channels.cache.get(`823225045231992892`).send('You cant send messages from now!')
    }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62816192/10675707) you can get more information about how you can change permissions.

```js
    setTimeout(() => {
      var channel = client.channels.cache.get(`823225045231992892`) 
      
        channel.send("You cant send messages from now!");
        channel.overwritePermissions(
          [
            {
              id: channel.guild.id,
              deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES"],
            },
          ],
          "Deny access to send messages"
        );
    }, 10000);
```